# driver not found when trying to connect a wired printer

Tags: windows, windows-10

i just bought a wired hp deskjet 2130all in one printer and when I try to install it I get a red x and then it comes up driver not found please ca you help

Comment: Have you installed the Windows 10 drivers?

Comment: how do you do that

Comment: You download them.  [HP DeskJet 2130 All-in-One Printer - Windows 10 Driver](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/COL60948/al-146800-2/DJ2130_Full_WebPack_40.11.1124.exe).  [HP Customer Support - Software and Driver Downloads](https://www.support.hp.com/id-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-2130-all-in-one-printer-series/7174550/model/7174551)

Comment: Can someone down vote this question on my behalf please?

Comment: @james, assuming this is a USB printer, it is important to install the driver before you connect the printer (the driver installation wizard will tell you when to attach the printer).

Answer (score 0):

Before using printer, you need to install its driver which is compatible with current system at first. 
Go to HP official website to download HP DeskJet 2130 series Full Feature Software and Drivers.

HP DeskJet 2130 All-in-One Printer

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-2130-all-in-one-printer-series/7174550/model/7174551